# PCB Layout. The path between pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, routing

Is it correct to have a path between the two pads. The width of the path is 8mil

[image]

Comment: It's a way. Whether it is correct or not depends on whether it meets your design rules.

Comment: You also had to check the limits of the PCB manufacturer. 8mil traces are still standard, though.

Comment: Those are the power pins for the TL084 (VCC+/VCC-). Such thin power traces with no bypass caps in sight feels wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. This picture is only for the illustration purposes and I will not use it for the power ones. I just wonder if it is generally OK, taking into consideration all the circumstances (like current, voltage etc).

Comment: Two traces between those pads is possible for some PCB manufacturers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the width/thickness of the track can carry the current

AND

The clearance between track and pad can withstand the voltage difference

AND

Neither track or pads are sensitive analogue nodes

THEN

It's probably OK